# Proving that a Series Converges Conditionally

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

So, I was suppose to prove that the series$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_n$ is conditionally convergent given $\{a_n\}$ is the sequence

$$
a_n=
\begin{cases}
1/k&\mathrm{if\ }n=2k-1,\\
-1/k&\mathrm{if\ }n=2k.\\
\end{cases}
$$

I know that $ a_n=\{1, -1, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2},...,\frac{1}{k}, -\frac{1}{k}, \frac{1}{k+1}, -\frac{1}{k+1}, ... \}$ but how do I show that it converges conditionally?

**correction: **  $\{1, -1/2, 1/3, -1/4, ...\}$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that your sequence is $\{1, -1/2, 1/3, -1/4, ...\}$ which is different than what you wrote.

Comment: @Tom ive got the logic of the piecewise sequence wrong. So this means that the partial sum will take the value$\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ right and so from here I can prove conditional convergence via alternating series test and its failure to meet the criteria of absolute convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Conditional convergence means that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_k$ converges, but $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left|a_k\right|$ doesn't. Obviously,

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\left|a_k\right| = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac 1 k$$
is the harmonic series, which is divergent.

To prove the convergence of  $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}a_k$, you can use the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: Hi @adjan, thanks for the hints. I have a rough sketch of which tests to use but the only problem lies with using the correct partial sum that arises from $a_n$. Im not whether my second attempt in the comments is correct tho.

Comment: You don't need partial sums to apply the alternating series test. you only have to show that $\left|a_k\right| = \left |\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right| = \frac{1}{k}$ decreases monotonically and converges to 0.

Comment:  thanks a lot